# Addclass is not a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a mouseover function that should add a class to my viewport element, but i get an error in firebug when I mouseover: TypeError: jQuery(...).addclass is not a function.

the HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title('|','true','right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url'     ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
<header>
<div class="main-logo">
    <div id="site-title">

    </div><!--.site-title-->
</div><!--main-logo-->

<div class="header-right">
</div><!--header-right-->
</header>

<nav class="main">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>

<div class="viewport">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
jQuery('nav .home a').mouseover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').addclass('.viewporthome');
  });
});
 //--><!]]></script>
</div>
</div>
```

The related styles are:

```
    .viewport
    {
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
position: relative;
top: -90px;
margin: 0 auto;

}

.viewporthome
{
background-image: url('images/Screen2.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: relative;

}
```

The JS file is:

```
      var hoverhome = 'url("images/Screen2.png")';
  var empty = '';
  var success = 'SUCCESS!';
  //home
  jQuery('nav .home a').hover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', hoverhome);

  });
  jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function()
  {    
        jQuery('.viewport').css('background-image', empty);
  });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this :

```
jQuery('.viewport').addClass('viewporthome');
```

`addClass` need a capital "C".

Also, when adding class, you dont need to put the "." in the string or your class will be `..viewporthome`.

Comment: GREAT SUCCESS! "Also, when adding class, you dont need to put the "." in the string or your class will be ..viewporthome." Works perfectly, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) instead of `addclass`

Comment: Javascript is very, very, very case-sensitive

Comment: no, it is just case-sensitive :)

Comment: That did work, thank you. Do either of you see why the background image won't show up now that it should be adding that class?

Comment: @Chris: probably the path on your css class is wrong.

Comment: Or that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16865555/2324107

Comment: @Claudio Redi tested the css path, image loads when I append the .viewporthome class into the viewport class manaually.

Comment: But when added using addClass(), it is not working? Is it?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a class:

```
$(".something").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("style");
});
```

Removing a class:

```
$(".something").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("style");
});
```

Comment: I had the issue when trying `this.addClass('class-name');` using `$(this).addClass('class-name')` helped thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra dot and use `addClass()` not addclass()

```
jQuery('.viewport').addClass('viewporthome');
```

Comment: This did remove the error, but the image is still not showing up

Comment: Well, is it the same question as your original one?

Comment: Not sure which one you mean by my original one, but with this code I figure the added class would make the Screen2 image appear in the viewport div when I mouseover the home button

Answer (score 0):

Check your capitalization. The addClass method has a capital 'C'.

[jQuery addClass Method](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

If the image still isn't showing up it is probably an issue with the relative path to your image. If the images folder isn't in the same directory as your Javascript file you may have to modify the path. I can't tell exactly what you would need to do without knowing your directory structure.

Comment: Structure: C:/wamp/www/sitename/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/Screen2.png